# Estimating number of slaves imported before 1790

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

I have a statistics problem I am having a hard time figuring out how to model mathematically.

The 1790 US Census counted 697,681 slaves and 59,196 free Africans in the United States.

(A) assume importation began in 1620 and increased according to some unknown exponential function

(B) assume a rate of natural increase at 2.5% per annum

(C) assume all free Africans are manumitted slaves or their descendants and the rate of manumission is constant during the entire period

Given these assumptions, what is the function that would describe the annual number of slaves imported during that time (1620-1790)?

Comment: I assume this question is being asked in good faith, but I find it rather disturbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S(t)$ and $F(t)$ are the populations of slaves and free Africans at time $t$, I would interpret your assumptions as saying

$$ \eqalign{S' &= A e^{kt} + r S\cr
            F' &= r F + m S\cr
            S(0) &= F(0) = 0}$$
where $r = 0.025$ is the rate of natural increase (assumed here to apply to both slaves and free Africans, though I doubt that is realistic), $m$ the per capita rate of manumission, $A$ the
initial importation rate, $k$ the rate of increase of the importation rate,
and $t$ is measured in years after 1620.

However, note that there are three unknown parameters $A$, $k$ and $m$ and only two items of data ($S(170)$ and $F(170)$), so you're not going to be able to determine those parameters.

Comment: Right, I was gathering there might be a problem in estimating k without further data. I was thinking it should be possible to compute the manumission rate, however, given that we know the numbers of the free at the terminus. In terms of available data, the rate of increase in importation at the end (1760-1790) is much better known than at the beginning.

Comment: So, it seems from your answer that the way to do this is by making a system of differential equations. That makes sense.